# Rocket Chat Setting User Presence, REST API

Tags: react-native, rocket.chat

*I'm trying to integrate Rocket Chat to a React Native Application I'm Currently Building, But i cant seem to find a way to change the User Presence, How do i do that? PS: I'm using Rocket Chat REST API. Rocket Chat Server Is Hosted On A Local PC With Ubuntu 18.04.*

Comment: Hello @thorin can you please tell me how to integrate rocket.chat in react native?

Comment: use their REST API DOCS. or I can help u out with some helper classes I made for myself. u can find me on "open.rocket.chat". as Prem8 @Kamlesh